# Fluent ConfigurationSourceBuilder Causes InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, unity-container, enterprise-library

I am building a logging DLL that will simplify EntLib 5 Logging Application Block.  I am using `ConfigurationSourceBuilder` to configure the logging for my application.  I currently have this:

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

        configBuilder.ConfigureLogging().WithOptions
            .DoNotRevertImpersonation()
            .LogToCategoryNamed("EventLog")
                .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()
                .SendTo.EventLog("Event Log Listener")
                .FormatWithSharedFormatter("Text Formatter")
                .ToLog("Application")
            .LogToCategoryNamed("Email")
                .SendTo.Email("Email Trace Listener")
                .To(ToEmail)
                .From(fromEmail)
                .WithSubjectStart("Error:")
                .UsingSmtpServer(SmtpServer)
                .UsingSmtpServerPort(SmtpServerPort)
                .Unauthenticated()
                .FormatWithSharedFormatter("Text Formatter")
            .LogToCategoryNamed("LogFile")
                .SendTo.FlatFile("Flat File Trace Listener")
                .ToFile(logFileName)
                .WithHeader("------------------------------")
                .WithFooter("------------------------------")
                .FormatWithSharedFormatter("Text Formatter");

        var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
        configBuilder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
        EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = 
            EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

The program will build and I will reference it in the main app. When it goes to set up the configuration it blows up with this error:

```
InvalidOperationException - The current type,
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.ILogFormatter, 
is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

Just in case this matters, the main app is using Unity as an IoC.  Do I need to resolve the DLL with Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue is that you haven't actually created a Formatter.  You've referenced an existing formatter by name with the statement `.FormatWithSharedFormatter("Text Formatter")`.

If you define a formatter using `FormatterBuilder` then it should be OK:

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

configBuilder.ConfigureLogging().WithOptions
.DoNotRevertImpersonation()
.LogToCategoryNamed("EventLog")
    .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()
    .SendTo.EventLog("Event Log Listener")
    .FormatWith(
        new FormatterBuilder()
            .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")
            .UsingTemplate("Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}Message: {message}{newline}Category: {category}")
        )
    .ToLog("Application")
.LogToCategoryNamed("Email")
    .SendTo.Email("Email Trace Listener")
    .To(ToEmail)
    .From(fromEmail)
    .WithSubjectStart("Error:")
    .UsingSmtpServer(SmtpServer)
    .UsingSmtpServerPort(SmtpServerPort)
    .Unauthenticated()
    .FormatWithSharedFormatter("Text Formatter")
.LogToCategoryNamed("LogFile")
    .SendTo.FlatFile("Flat File Trace Listener")
    .ToFile(logFileName)
    .WithHeader("------------------------------")
    .WithFooter("------------------------------")
    .FormatWithSharedFormatter("Text Formatter");
```

Comment: Wow so simple! Thank a lot Tuzo